# Sails.JS Socket in Overridden Actions of the Controller

Tags: websocket, sails.js

I've overridden an action in the controller that was generated from a blueprint API in Sails.JS.

I used the create action. Now I can't get a Sails.JS socket event from that action anymore, however, other actions are working fine.

```
io.socket.on('posts', function gotHelloMessage(data) {
      console.log('Post!', data);
    });
io.socket.get('/posts', function gotResponse(body, response) {
    console.log('Posts: ', body);
})
```

What's the way to implement so that the create action also generates the event with my newly implemented actions?

```
create: function(req, res) {
    if (
      !_.has(req.body, "title") ||
      !_.has(req.body, "body") ||
      !_.has(req.body, "category")
    ) {
      return res.serverError("No field should be empty.");
    }
    var uploadPath = "../../assets/posts";
    return req
      .file("thumbnail")
      .upload({ dirname: uploadPath }, async function(err, uploadedFiles) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        let post;
        try {
          post = await Posts.create({
            title: req.body.title,
            body: req.body.body,
            category: req.body.category,
            thumbnail:
              uploadedFiles.length === 0
                ? ""
                : uploadedFiles[0].fd.split("/").reverse()[0]
          }).fetch();
          return res.json({ result: post });
        } catch (err) {
          return res.json({ error: err });
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, what version of Sails are you using? Check out these docs on [Blueprint API](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) and [Blueprint actions - see: Overriding blueprint actions](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints/blueprint-actions)

Comment: i completely forgot what i was doing with that. thanks anyway. i will check it later when i use sails js framework again.